# How to submit login request through boost beast?

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-beast

I'm trying to login the site using boost beast, but in the result get only page with changed fields

```
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/beast.hpp"

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    asio::io_context context;

    beast::tcp_stream stream(context);
    stream.connect(tcp::resolver(context).resolve("site.com", "http"));

    http::request<http::string_body> request;
    request.version(11);
    request.method(http::verb::post);
    request.target("/login.php?redirect=somepage");
    request.set(http::field::host, "site.com");
    request.set(http::field::content_type, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.body() = "fusername=USERNAME&fpassword=PASSWORD";
    request.prepare_payload();

    boost::beast::http::write(stream, request);

    boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::dynamic_body> res;

    boost::beast::http::read(stream, buffer, res);

    std::cout << res;
}
```

The method part of this site is looking like

```
<form action="./login.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="somepage">
    <div><b>Enter your username and password to log in.</b></div>
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on" style="width:100px;text-align:right;">Username:</span>
        <input type="text" class="post input" name="fusername" size="25" maxlength="40" value="" tabindex="101">
    </div>
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on" style="width:100px;text-align:right;">Password:</span>
        <input type="password" class="post input" name="fpassword" value="" tabindex="102" size="25" maxlength="32">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="bold long btn" value="Log in" style="margin:0 auto;">

</form>
```

res is equal to the page except value fields are looking like `value="USERNAME"`

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is actually input value send in the body as well, not used as URL parameter. Try changing:

```
request.target("/login.php");
```

and

```
request.body() = "fusername=USERNAME&fpassword=PASSWORD&redirect=somepage";
```

Comment: changed
`/login.php` to `/login.php?redirect=somepage`
and
`fusername=USERNAME&fpassword=PASSWORD` to `fusername=USERNAME&fpassword=PASSWORD&redirect=somepage`

Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer, hope it will help you.

1. You need to use escape sequences on string "action" when you are sending it as param
2. If the site has the button with name and value you need to pass it as param to POST too
3. POST just will change state but it will not return you page use GET after this
4. If site sent you the cookie in the answer than you need to add it to GET request

And yeah, if you can't create HTTP request you can just log in or whatever in a browser (Firefox for example) and take raw requests from it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/beast.hpp"

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;

static std::string const host = "site.com";
static std::string const redirected = "/somepage=1";
static std::string const redirected_escaped = "somepage%3D1";

static std::string const username = "USERNAME";
static std::string const password = "PASSWORD";

int main() {
    try {
        std::ofstream output("../output.html");

        asio::io_context context;

        beast::tcp_stream stream(context);
        stream.connect(tcp::resolver(context).resolve(host, "http"));

        std::string cookie;

        {
            http::request<http::string_body> request(http::verb::post, "/login.php", 11);
            request.set(http::field::host, host);
            request.set(http::field::content_type, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            request.body() =
                    "redirect=" + redirected_escaped +
                    "&login_username=" + username +
                    "&login_password=" + password +
                    "&login=Log+in";
            request.prepare_payload();

            std::cout << request << std::endl;

            boost::beast::http::write(stream, request);

            boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
            boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::dynamic_body> res;

            boost::beast::http::read(stream, buffer, res);

            cookie = std::string(res.base().at(http::field::set_cookie));

            std::cout << "Cookie: " << cookie << std::endl;
        }

        {
            http::request<http::string_body> request(http::verb::get, redirected, 11);
            request.set(http::field::host, host);
            request.set(http::field::cookie, cookie);

            std::cout << request << std::endl;

            boost::beast::http::write(stream, request);

            boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
            boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::dynamic_body> res;

            boost::beast::http::read(stream, buffer, res);

            output << beast::buffers_to_string(res.body().data());
        }

    } catch (boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error> const &wrapexcept) {
        std::cout << wrapexcept.what();
    }

}
```